# Illegal instruction CMOVE - Compile for i586

Tags: c, compilation, cross-compiling, i386

I have a x86_64 machine and want to compile for a machine, which has i586 arch.

I installed: `libc6-dev-x32` and `libc6-dev:i386`

Then I tried to compile a simple hello world like this:

```
gcc -m32 -march=i586 -mcpu=i586 test.c -o test -static
```

It works on my machine but on the target I get the illegal instruction error on the `CMOVE` instruction. So he doesn't know `CMOVE`.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: If I remember correctly cmov is introduced in i686. You need to track down which part of the code is compiled with i686 assumption.

Comment: It is just a hello world. So what could it be there? Can't I tell gcc to not use cmove?

Comment: My guess is: the libc makes use of the cmove instruction somewhere, and since you link the libc of the build system statically it is used at the target system, too. Does it help to omit `-static`?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32781281

Comment: Another thing: My distro (debian jessie) provides a package "libc6-dev-i386", it should help to link against _that_ version of the glibc.

Comment: If that is an i586 machine, it is not x86_**64**. Install i386 libraries and compile for that target.

Comment: @Olaf the development machine is x86_64 and the target machine is i586

Comment: @M.M: Maybe for gcc and/or the libs, i586 implies PPro, not original Pentium instruction set/arch which OP seems to need. So target would either be i486, or i386. Typically, there are either libs for new arch or i386; i486 pre-build installs are more rare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You statically link against the glibc of your host system, which makes use of the `CMOV*`-instructions. So compiler switches won't help.

One option is to link against `dietlibc`:

- Install the package `dietlibc-dev:i386`
- Link against it: `diet gcc -m32 -march=i586 -mcpu=i586 test.c -o test -static`

Now your binary should not include the offending instructions.

Comment: It worked fine, but after using fopen() for example I again get the illegal instruction error. What can I do?

Comment: @Donovaaan It surprises me that the dietlibc-binaries use instructions which your target machine doesn't support. Can you identify which one it is?

Comment: I made this: `objdump -D test | grep cmove` and I got this single instruction: `8048ba9: 0f 44 c3              cmove  %ebx,%eax`. Is this what you mean? The  code is just this: http://pastebin.com/Ar7dM3qe Thank you so much for helping!

Comment: @Donovaaan Can you upload the binary somewhere?

Comment: That's interesting... Indeed this cmove is not present in my dietlibc-binaries and is exactly what causes you trouble again here. Which version do you use? I use 0.33~cvs20120325-6 from debian jessie

Comment: My version is: diet version 0.33~cvs20120325-6 on Ubuntu 15.10 :(

Comment: You could try to install the package from debian jessie on your ubuntu, that should help

Comment: @Donovaaan it should work to download this: http://mirror.de.leaseweb.net/debian/pool/main/d/dietlibc/dietlibc-dev_0.33~cvs20120325-6_i386.deb and install it with `dpkg -i`

Answer (score 0):

A quick check on debian / jessie, and command

```
objdump -D /lib32/libc-2.19.so | grep cmove
```

reveals that there are *cmove* instructions there. [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_instruction_listings) mentions that they were added for pentium pro.

According to this [blog](http://ph0b.com/adding-dev-tools-gcc-make-to-galileo-sd-image/)

> Sept. 2014 update: GCC and other dev tools are now part of the
>   official linux image you can download from Intel Developer Zone.

there should be something available either [IoT installers page](https://software.intel.com/en-us/iot/downloads) or [Software Downloads for Boards and Kits](https://communities.intel.com/docs/DOC-22226)

Building a cross-compiler toolset could be another option.